# How do I exclude invisible layers from SVG code?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

In Illustrator, when I save a file as an SVG, the code includes everything on the artboard, even layers that are not visible. How do I save SVGs which ONLY include visible layers?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you found the solution yet, but here's what worked for me.

1. Set the layer to exclude from SVG to a template layer, then hide it.
2. Save As -> Select SVG
3. When the dialog comes up, hit the button for show svg code, or hit save.

Comment: Seems hacky, but did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a good script to export layer to svg,eps,fxg,png,pdf file. It can export to multiple files by layer or only the selected layer.

http://www.tbyrne.org/export-illustrator-layers-to-svg-files

Answer (score 0):

If you're exporting lots of artboards, put all the artwork onto one layer. This will stop there being empty layers for each SVG.